# MySQL8 - more cores vs higher cpu frequency?

Tags: mysql

Do you know any benchmarks which compare both cases? What is better?

Comment: `mysqlslap` is a bundled tool intended to simulate workload - refer to official documentation for further info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, look at your workload.

If you will have only one process running at a time, then only 1 core is used.

If you could have thousands of processes running "simultaneously", don't.  Don't even benchmark more than 64 threads.  Figure out how many your application will realistically receive, and limit the benchmarking to that.  I'm not talking about threads that are sitting idle; they don't count.  Beyond about 64, MySQL stumbles over itself; throughput stalls; latency increases.  Very few big production systems have more than a few dozen threads ever active (not Sleep) at the same time, even if they are cranking out thousands of 'queries per second'.

In both scenarios, CPU clock speed is more important.

But, much more important than clock speed is optimizing the query and the schema, especially the indexes.

Also important: Disk speed.  Use SSD for high traffic.

Amount of RAM -- not useful to go past twice the size of the data.